# handle structural try catch block in for loop

Tags: c#

How to handle the try catch block with keeping the for loop runing?

In my case

```
foreach (var str in strArr)
{
    try
   {
       var s1 = gets1(str);
       try
      {
          var s2 = gets2(s1);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          myLog(ex.message);
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       myLog(ex.message);
   }
}
```

Question 1)

If any exception occured, the foreach loop keep be killed.

Question 2)

If gets2(s1) gets error, which catch block will catch that exception?

Comment: Well, think about it logically, what do you think the answers to your questions are and why do you think that?

Comment: Please rephrase the question 1. For question 2,  of course the inner catch will handle the exception. Debugging would help you better.

Comment: why don't you raise exception from gets1 and gets2 functions to answer your question. "throw new Exception" should help you.

Comment: @Vicky so there is the question. if an exception occurred in gets1(), will gets2() be executed?

Comment: I don't know what's going on here, but it doesn't smell great.

Comment: @kingyau If there's an exception that isn't handled at a "lower" level (i.e. gets1 doesn't handle the exception itself), the code inside the try block will stop executing at the point of the exception and proceed to the Catch block.

Answer (score 0):

the loop would not be killed because your capturing your exception so your code will continue to run.

Also re Exception handling it depends on where the exception occured.

When an exception occurs the exception will be passed back up to the first available Exception handler.

So if  S2 were to have an exception it would be caught here,

```
try
  {
      var s2 = gets2(s1);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      myLog(ex.message);
      Exception caught here
  }
```

Also, if your exception were caused before you got to your second try

```
 try
 {
   var s1 = gets1(str);
   Exception Caught here
   ....
   other try... 
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   myLog(ex.message);
   Exception would be caught here. 

 }
```

Comment: one more question, if gets1() has its own try catch block and an exception has occurred inside gets1() method. Will the  `try
  {
      var s2 = gets2(s1);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      myLog(ex.message);
      Exception caught here
  }`be run?

Comment: it depends if the exception happens before or after the nested try catch block